# Whats included in "ALL [PRIVILEGES]"?

Tags: mysql, privileges, sql-grant

Which privileges are given when I grant "ALL PRIVILEGES"?

```
-> ALL [PRIVILEGES] Grant all privileges at specified access level except GRANT OPTION
```

Does this include "FILE"-privilege?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All means all excpet GRANT i.e,

```
CREATE
DROP
LOCK TABLES
REFERENCES
EVENT
ALTER
DELETE
INDEX
INSERT
SELECT
UPDATE
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES
TRIGGER
CREATE VIEW
SHOW VIEW
ALTER ROUTINE
CREATE ROUTINE
EXECUTE
FILE
CREATE TABLESPACE
CREATE USER
PROCESS
PROXY
RELOAD
REPLICATION CLIENT
REPLICATION SLAVE
SHOW DATABASES
SHUTDOWN
SUPER
```